# Is it possible to remove an item from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove the first entry in a dictionary, so it stays a certain size and doesn't grow too large.  I'm looping through voltage readings, storing it in a dictionary and then run it through a machine learning model to make predictions.  How do I remove the oldest (first) entry in the dictionary to keep the model the same size.

```
thisdict = {}

while True:
   dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = Power
   if len(dictionary_power_readings) > 400 : 
      dictionary_power_readings.popitem()
      #run machine learning model on dictionary_power_readings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6+ maintains dcitionary insertion order by default, so you could do something like :

```
if len(dictionary_power_readings) > 400 : 
    del dictionary_power_readings[list(dictionary_power_readings.keys())[0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `deque` from `collections`:

```
import collections

dq = collections.deque(maxlen=400)

while True:
    dq.append((time.time(), Power))
```

Example:

```
import random

for i in range(500):
    dq.append((i, random.randint(0, 50)))
```

```
>>> len(dq)
400

>>> dq[0]
(100, 8)

>>> dq[-1]
(499, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries has the method keys() which returns all keys, so you get the first one like that:

```
keys = list(dictionary.keys())

dictionary.pop(keys[0])
```

I'm using my cellphone, so i can't try it to verify if that works, but i hope that can help you.